# Trying to concatenate a variable to refer to a field

Tags: vba, variables

The Variable I want to use will come from the user and is a company name.
I need to concatenate the string. One field name is "[Amazon Emp Nbr]".

```
Dim strCompany as String
MsgBox([Amazon Emp Nbr])' This works! I get the value of the field!

StrCompany = "Amazon"
MsgBox("[" & strCompany & " Emp Nbr]")
```

This does not work! It returns the string [Amazon Emp Nbr] Not the value of the field.

Answer (score 5):

Use Range and not the `[]`.  the `[]` do not allow the use of variables:

```
Dim strCompany as String
MsgBox([Amazon Emp Nbr])' This works! I get the value of the field!

StrCompany = "Amazon"
MsgBox Range( strCompany & " Emp Nbr").value
```